# Restore Deleted Azure Web App Cloud Exception

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

So someone I handed over an Azure web app to managed to delete the site and now wants it back.

I was running it as a small project on a free tier, so I don't have any active backups or anything. I tried using the new [Webapp Undelete](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/09/24/announcing-webapps-undelete-preview/) feature, but every time I ran `Restore-AzureRmDeletedWebApp` as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/restore-azurermdeletedwebapp?view=azurermps-6.11.0), I get the following error:

```
Restore-AzureRmDeletedWebApp : An error has occurred.
At line:1 char:1
+ Restore-AzureRmDeletedWebApp -ResourceGroupName xxxx -Name xxxx -Tar ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Restore-AzureRmDeletedWebApp], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.WebApps.Cmdlets.BackupRestore.RestoreAzureDeletedWebApp
```

What does this even mean? Is there a way to fix it? Is there a way to access the backup that Azure has (running `Get-AzureRmDeletedWebApp` definitely still lists the deleted app) manually? Or is the site just gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per this [doc](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/09/24/announcing-webapps-undelete-preview/), currently, Azure App Service Undelete is available for all App Service Plans, **from Basic and up.** Only sites deleted in the past 30 days can be restored. It works for me without errors on a basic plan. You can see the output below.

[image]

If I try to restore a web app on a free tier, I have the same error as you, also, I have a 404 Web Site not found error even the restored app service is created or displayed in the Azure portal. It seems that it's not supported to restore a web app on a free tier currently.

If you have back up your web on Azure, you can [restore your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-restore) with its linked databases on-demand to a previous state, or create a new app based on one of your original app's backups. Restoring from backups is available to apps running in Standard and Premium tier.

Comment: Thanks. There wouldn't happen to be a way to update my deleted site to Basic and then restore the app, would there?

Comment: I don't think there is, If the web app service is deleted, the SCM site is also not found. Even you try to restore it to a target basic plan using that PowerShell. You will see a 404 Web Site not found error as my reply above mentioned when you access the website on the newly restored web app service

Answer (score 2):

The [`WebApps Undelete`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/09/24/announcing-webapps-undelete-preview/) is only available for Basic and Up tier for now.And I have tested it , It's successful in basic tier.

If your web runs on free tier and you don't have any backups ,you couldn't recover it by yourself.But you could still check whether all resources including local and deployment resources like GitHub etc have been deleted.

If so, you could contact the Microsoft Support ,maybe they could help you.

And if you have any questions, please let me know.